# how to make the annotation subtitle disappear from title menu?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

In my app am adding subtitle to annotation pin but don't want to show with pin. I am just using it for coding purpose. How can I hide?

Comment: do you want to show the callout without annotation Pin??

Comment: no I want to show the annotation without subtitle....

Comment: use [YourAnnotationView canShowCallout = NO];

Comment: i need to show title in callout but not subtitle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `subtitle` property of your annotation class is set to a non-blank value, it will display in the callout.

If you need to store data with the annotation but not display it in the callout, **create a separate property for it (that's not named `title`, `subtitle`, or `coordinate`)**.

Leave `subtitle` blank or just don't implement the property in your annotation class (it's optional).

Comment: Thanks Anna for looking at ny problem

Comment: can you suggest me through some code how to do it.....Thanks in adv

Comment: In your annotation class .h, add an NSString property just like subtitle but name it something else.  Then where you create annotations, set that property instead of subtitle.

Comment: Were you able to code it or do you need an actual example?

Comment: I added an example on your new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11931814/how-to-show-only-pinannotation-title-in-map-view